# Has a complex-orthogonal analog of the Schur decomposition ever been studied?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've looked around for a study of the following matrix decomposition: $A = QUQ^T$ where $A$ is a complex matrix, $QQ^T = I$, and $U$ is an upper triangular matrix.

It can be shown that not all matrices have such a factorization. To wit, consider any matrix $A$ such that $A = A^T$. If $A$ has an orthogonal Schur decomposition then $U^T = (Q^T A Q)^T = Q^T A Q = U$, so $U$ is diagonal. Now consider $A = \begin{pmatrix}2i & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. This matrix is symmetric but not diagonalizable, hence it doesn't admit an orthogonal Schur decomposition.

Comment: Trivial remark: the reason the standard proof fails is that if we use the standard inner product ($[v_1,\dots,v_n].[w_1,\dots,w_n] = v_1w_1+\dots+v_nw_n$), there can exist vectors that pair to zero with themselves. If one of these vectors is an eigenvector, then $Q^TQ$ will be diagonal with some entries 0.